# re-frame: No event handler registered

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

My re-frame views.cljs has:

```
(re-frame/dispatch [::re-graph/init
                    {:http-url "https://api.spacex.land/graphql"
                     :ws-url nil
                      :http-parameters {:with-credentials? false}}])

(re-frame/dispatch [::re-graph/query
                    "{ launches { id, mission_name } }"  ;; your graphql query
                    [::update-data]])
```

My events.cljs has:

```
(re-frame/reg-event-db
 ::update-data
 (fn [db [_ {:keys [data errors] :as payload}]]
   (-> db
     (assoc :errors errors)
     (assoc :data data))))
```

But I keep getting this error:

> core.cljs:3919 re-frame: no :event handler registered for: undefined

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to include the `nil` for the query variables

```
(re-frame/dispatch
 [::re-graph/query
  "{launches {id, mission_name}}"
  nil
  [:add-launches]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `:events/update-data` in `views.cljs`. The `::` refers to the current namespace (`:views/update-data`), and that event handler is not defined there, but in the `events` namespace.

Also note that you can use:

```
(-> db
   (assoc :errors errors
          :data data)))
```

saves you one `assoc`.

Comment: Changed it to:  
(re-frame/dispatch [::re-graph/query
                    "{ launches { id, mission_name } }"  ;; your graphql query
                    [:events/add-launches]])`
I still see the same error in the console:
**re-frame: expected a vector, but got: ({:data {…}})**
**re-frame: no :event handler registered for: undefined**